# The restricted content is shown before redirection - Next.js - Next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to restrict a route and redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in. I am using Next.js 13 beta.

```
const { status } = useSession()
const router = useRouter()
if (status === 'unauthenticated')
router.push('/user/profile')
return <>Restricted content</>
```

However, the restricted page (Restricted content) is visible for a small amount of time before redirection.

I've tested it in the production environment, but there's no change. Could anyone please tell me whether I'm doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You could move your check to a component or function that gets called before your page content is rendered, for example, in a context, layout, getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, etc.

---

To make your current setup work, you must return content until the router pushes to a new route.

```
const { status } = useSession()
const { push }= useRouter()


// only call on page load or if the status or route changes
useEffect(()=>{
 if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
  router.push('/user/profile')
 }
},[ status, push ]);

// return unauthorized screen, loading component,
// or empty screen while you process the check
if(!status || status === "unauthenticated"){
   return null; //or <></> depending on your settings
}

return (
 <>restricted content</>
)
```

Comment: Thanks @sean for the reply. It worked however I had to make a slight change by adding a condition statement just before the return statement. `if(status && status === "authenticated") return <>Restricted content</>`